# Why does cp not copy a specified folder

Tags: bash, cp

let's say that I have a following file structure:

```
~/DIR1
-fileA
-DIR2
--fileB
```

Then, being in ~, I run this script:

```
cp DIR1 NEWDIR2
```

And just an error happens:

```
cp: omitting directory ‘DIR1’
```

I understand why nothing from DIR1 gets copied (because I didn't use -r switch that would enforce recursion) but I'd expect the DIR1 folder itself copied to NEWDIR2 (so practically a creation of a new "NEWDIR2" in ~ or a creation of ~/NEWDIR2/DIR1).

Could someone explain to me why is my expectation wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the GNU info page for cp:

> By default, 'cp' does not copy directories.  However, the '-R', '-a',
>   and '-r' options cause 'cp' to copy recursively by descending into
>   source directories and copying files to corresponding destination
>   directories.

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html#cp-invocation

Comment: What somehow confuses me is that both man and gnu info page implicitly understand copying directories as copying sub directories while they, in fact, are not always the same thing... But thanks, I guess I'll just live with the fact that GNU documentation is not perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

cp cannot copy directories unless it is used with switches like -R , -r or -a.

[Click here for more info](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -r src dest #(OOPS!!)
```

The above behaves differently if dest exists or not.  this isn't dumb, if you think about it.
If you want to copy over one dir to another, use simply copy every dir and file in the source dir to the dest.

```
cp -r src/* dest
```

The above does what you want to do (use -a as needed) but you'll need to use "midnight commander" or GLOBIGNORE (too technical) to copy the hidden files as well. (because * ignores the hidden files)